# How to make a "reference" to an array by string in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, reference

I have a problem which I'm unable to solve (in an easy way) at the moment:

```
$clients = array("A", "B");

$array_data_A = array(
    array("1000733", "1.6.0"),
    array("1000733", "1.8.0"),
    array("1000733", "1.8.1"),
    array("1000733", "1.8.2"),
    array("1000733", "1.8.3"),
    array("1000733", "1.8.4"),
);

$array_data_B = array(
    array("1000733", "1.6.0"),
    array("1000733", "1.8.0"),
    array("1000733", "1.8.1"),
    array("1000733", "1.8.2"),
    array("1000733", "1.8.3"),
    array("1000733", "1.8.4"),
);
```

Now I can make this:

```
foreach ($clients as $client) {

    // won't work
    $data_array = '$array_data'.$client;
    getsqldata($client, $data_array);

    // works
    switch ($client) {
        case "A":
            getsqldata($client, $array_data_A);
            break;
    }
}
```

**Is it the only way to solve this with a case function?** Or is there a possibility to store a string in a variable which can be used as a reference to the correct array?

Because I have many clients (50+) I'm searching for a dynamic way to solve this...

Comment: Instead of dynamic variables use __subarrays__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using following code:

```
$str = "array_data_".$client;
$data_array = $$str;
```

[Here is the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Answer (score 2):

You were missing few things one of them is `_` with in the string.

[**Try sample code here**](https://eval.in/870086)

**Change this to:**

```
$data_array = '$array_data'.$client;
```

**This:**

```
$data_array = ${'array_data_' . $client};
```